# function to check if user text is valid

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function so that if the user clicks the Update button AND the text in the textbox is a valid text(only the text from the array should be valid ie. text1, text2, text3). Then, it echo's the number assosiated to the text in the array so if text1 is entered, it should echo 10. I made a function to do it but it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on the foreach loop line.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id='usertext' name='usertext' size='15' />
<input type='submit' name='update' id='update' value='Update' />
```

**PHP:**

```
public currenttext = 0;

$config['text'] = array(
    10 => 'text1',
    25 => 'text2',
    50 => 'text3'
);


public function set_text($validtext) {
    foreach($this->config['text'] as $key => $value) { // <-- foreach loop
        if($key == $validtext){
            $this->currenttext = $value;
        }
    }
}

if ($_POST['update') {
    $this->set_text($_POST['usertext'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['update']) ) {
    $this->set_text( $_POST['usertext'] );
}
```

Also flip the `array`;

```
$config['text'] = array(
    'text1' => 10,
    'text2' => 25,
    'text3' => 50
);
```

Finally change the `set_text` method to something like this:

```
// $validtext could be text1 or text2 or text3 from user
public function set_text($validtext) {
    if(array_key_exists($validtext, $this->config['text'])) {
        $this->currenttext = $this->config['text'][$validtext];
    }
}
```

Integrate these in your class properly, it'll work. Also check [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) on `PHP` manual.

Comment: I realized right after I posted the question that I had to flip the array. I am glad you understood the problem correctly because this is exactly what I wanted. Couple follow ups before I mark this the right answer. 1) Is this the best way to do it? 2) Can you explain why you have $this->config['text'][$validtext]; beside each other?

Comment: In so many ways it could be done but this is a neat and clean way, `foreach` is a little expensive here in `IMO`, Using `$this->config['text'][$validtext]` I've accessed the multi-dimensional [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Is there any way you can provide me with a foreach loop way for this just for learning purposes?

Comment: The way you are using in your example is another way but your array needs to be flipped as i did in my answer, `array_search` is another way.

Comment: So my function was correct just needed to flip the array? Other than that thank you so much! Also to be noted that array_search is slower than array_key_exists

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you dont need a `foreach` loop, alternatively, you could also use `array_search()` to get the same goal. Consider this example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $usertext = $_POST['usertext'];
    $config['text'] = array(10 => 'text1', 25 => 'text2', 50 => 'text3');
    $key = array_search($usertext, $config['text']);
    if($key !== false) {
        echo $key;

    } else {
        // not found
    {
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type='text' id='usertext' name='usertext' size='15' /><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='update' id='update' value='Update' />
</form>
```